# Ask for help in making a pivot query working with a dynamic date range

Tags: sql, oracle, date, dynamic, pivot

I have Query 1 which returns7 dates in a week starts on Saturday and ends Friday.

```
 SELECT TRUNC(to_date('08-Jul-2018', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), 'IW') 
      + Level - (1+ TRUNC(to_date('08-Jul-2018', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), 'IW') 
      - TRUNC(to_date('08-Jul-2018', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), 'IW'))
   FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= 8; --great
```

Query two is a pivot query which is working fine right now with the hard coded dates.  How can I make the pivot (sum(counts) fro insrt in (.....)) dynamic instead ?  You see currently it is hard coded.  thanks

```
WITH tbl AS
  ( SELECT DISTINCT rowlabel,
    TO_CHAR(insrt ,'mm-dd-yyyy'),
    counts
  FROM tbl
  WHERE TRUNC(insrt) >= to_date('01-01-1900', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
  AND TRUNC(insrt)   <= to_date('12-31-4000', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
  )

SELECT                                             *
FROM tbl pivot ( 
  SUM(counts) FOR insrt IN ('06-30-2018','07-01-2018','07-02-2018','07-03-2018',
                            '07-04-2018','07-05-2018','07-06-2018')
) ;
```

Comment: There seems no relevance between Query 1 and 2, and please tell something more about the table `tbl`(structure and sample values).

Comment: Can you post what data you have and how you like the output to look like ?

Comment: Hello,thank you for your reply and kind help !

Comment: I am reposting my question in hope that it may be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
select trunc(to_date('04-JUL-2018', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), 'IW') + level -1
from dual
connect by level < 7;
--Query 2
WITH t AS
  ( SELECT DISTINCT test_number,
    TO_CHAR(insrt_dttm,'mm-dd-yyyy') AS date_without_time,
    rec_cnt
  from cdw_t.data_monitoring_result
  WHERE TRUNC(insrt_dttm) >= to_date('01-01-1900', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
  AND TRUNC(insrt_dttm)   <= to_date('12-31-4000', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
  )

SELECT                                             *
FROM t pivot ( SUM(rec_cnt) FOR date_without_time IN ('06-30-2018','07-01-2018','07-02-2018','07-03-2018','07-04-2018','07-05-2018','07-06-2018')) ;
TEST_NUMBER '06-30-2018'    '07-01-2018'    '07-02-2018'    '07-03-2018'    '07-04-2018'    '07-05-2018'    '07-06-2018'
51  10  10  10  11  14  14  14                  
1   179 179 179 179 179 179 179
30  127 127 127 127 127 127 127
53  594 594 594 594 594 594 226

Above is the sample output.  I was hoping that maybe I can use query 1 replace the hard coded dates in the FOR statement brackets.   I don't know how to write PL/SQL and not sure if it is possible to have a dynamic range inside the pivot for statement.
```

Comment: let me know if this is a better description of my questions.